# Cannot Deploy to Firebase Cloud Functions from Android Studio

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have recently updated to the new cloud functions per the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff).

I have made all of the updates to code that was previously responding to my `.onCreate()` method. However, now when I call `firebase deploy --only functions`, my terminal inside Android Studio simply freezes, and I check the logs in my Firebase console to see nothing has been executed.

Below is the associated code, node.js and JavaScript:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.trackVote = 
functions.firestore.document('Polls/{pollId}/responses/{userId}')
.onCreate(change, context => {

       const data = change.after.data();
       const answerSelected = data.answer;

       const answerRef = admin.firestore().doc(`Polls/${event.params.pollId}/answers/${answerSelected}`);
       const voteCountRef = admin.firestore.doc(`Polls/${event.params.pollId}/vote_count`);

        return admin.firestore().runTransaction(t => {
                    return t.get(answerRef)
                        .then(doc => {
                            if (doc.data()) {
                                t.update(answerRef, { vote_count: doc.data().vote_count + 1 });
                            }
                        }
                };
        //do not add to Git
         return admin.firestore().runTransaction(t => {
            return t.get(voteCountRef)
                .then(doc =>){
                    if (doc.data()){
                        t.update(voteCountRef, {vote_count:doc.data().vote_count+1});
                    }
                }
         };

});
```

EDIT: Error finally came through:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:18:11
```

Comment: You mention runTransaction in the title.  Why do you think that's relevant here?  Are you saying that if you deploy a function without a transaction, it works OK?

Comment: BTW, you have two conflicting return statements in your function.  You can't return, then return again after that.

Comment: I was actually able to deploy in 0.9.1, I am unable after the update. And yes, .runTransaction() is somewhat irrelevant, I simply cannot deploy at all thanks for quick response

Comment: Is it also relevant which shell you're using to run the deploy?

Comment: Very new to cloud functions, what do you mean by shell?

Comment: You said you ran the command in Android Studio.  What about some other terminal?

Comment: I can try that, I was not having issues within AS previously. It could indeed be the case, but I was calling firebase init from AS and it was working without issues, so I am led to believe it is the actually function being invoked that is causing the "freeze"

Comment: A deploy does not invoke the function.  It runs in Cloud Functions in response to an event that happens in your project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169811/discussion-between-tccpg288-and-doug-stevenson).

Comment: Sorry, but your code is syntactically incorrect. You still have the problem you already posted about ` .then(doc =>){` (that `)` is not supposed to be there), but now you're also missing many closing `)` after closures. Stack Overflow is not an efficient tool for helping with such mistakes. In fact, a much simpler tool like jslint can point them out to you much more quickly than we can.

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. You could also use the Admin SDK in a local Node.js process, which can be debugged with a local debugger. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Comment: Much appreciated I will use those resources and then proceed